# Changing x axis ticks to desired value.

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to generate a few graphs with matplotlib. I have a few specific time points that I want to represent on the x axis i.e. 0, 8, 24 and 72. The default plots them on a range from 0 to 120. I'd like to change this so that there are only 4 evenly spaced points. I tried

```
x = ['0','8','24','72']
```

But plotting this to my `"x"` but that was ignored and plotted normally.
Is there a way to change the x axis ticks to specific points on a line graph?

Comment: You could explicitly set where you want to tick marks with plt.xticks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`plt.xticks()`**
An example program that does what you need.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

x = np.linspace(0,5,4)
y = np.sin(x)

xticks = ['0','8','24','72']

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xticks(x,xticks) # This makes your desired x ticks
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Just wanted to add that making     x = [0,8,24,72]     still spaced the points at different distances and just removed all numbers on the x axis except for the four in xticks. To change this I called     x = [1,2,3,4]

Comment: @Amos you mean you have more than 4 x variables?

Comment: No, I have 4 x variables. Your answer was exactly what I was looking for. Part of my problem was also calling the x variables according to the name I wanted to give them so they all had a different distance. I added my comment to help anybody who might find this wnswer and be doing the same thing I did.